# Adding dynamic filter in suitelet

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I have created a suite which contains a list field for the customer.when the end user selects the customer in the multi-select field the projects which are related to the customer have to set.For this I have written a client script field change action It is working in admin part but it is not working in employee center. please, anyone has alternate solution for this post your answers.

Thanks!

Comment: Place some code in your question otherwise, we can't tell why it doesn't work.

Comment: Give script access for Specific roles or desired Person. Manage the roles and add the further permission to the employees.

Answer (score 0):

On the change action you can call a suitelet to get the projects list by customer.
On the suitelet, perform a search with the required customer as criteria and send the list in the response and populate the drop down with those values on the client side.
Set this suitelet to run as Admin, this way you will get all the projects you need without role restrictions.

Be very careful with the data that the Suitelet is returning since you will be running as admin without any native netsuite role restrictions and validations.